# A command from a context menu that does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Well, I have a WPF project and I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I'm using C# and XAML, and I'm using the MVVM pattern.

The problem I have must be simple but I just can't see why it's not working.

Alright, so I have a project with a ListBox. In that ListBox are many ChatNodes; each represented visually. The visual element for a ChatNode is here:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="NodeVisualTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Border BorderThickness="2" Margin="2" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.SelectionMode, Converter={StaticResource SelectionModeToColourConverter}}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ChatNodeMenu}">
                    <StackPanel Opacity="{Binding IsInvisibleNode, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=VisibleToOpacityConverter}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="Test" Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NodeText}" Background="Aqua"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text="Type here" MinWidth="50"/>
                            <Image Source="{StaticResource ImgFolder}" Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

I draw your attention to the BorderBrush for the Border. I will show that again here:

```
BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.SelectionMode, Converter={StaticResource SelectionModeToColourConverter}}"
```

This code sits inside a ListBoxItem and is able to find the parent ListBox and then access a property of it. This works fine. The property is in a view model called ChatNodeListViewModel and looks like this:

```
private int _selectionMode = 0;
    public int SelectionMode
    {
        get { return _selectionMode; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectionMode != value)
            {
                _selectionMode = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectionMode");
            }
        }
    }
```

I mention it specifically because another thing which is almost identical is not working, even though this BorderBrush code is working.

So, on to the not working part.

In that same ControlTemplate above, we see a ContextMenu, called 'ChatNodeMenu'. This is as follows:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ChatNodeMenu" >
            <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.RemoveChatNodeCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
```

It has the same binding, only this time it is for a Command called 'RemoveChatNodeCommand'. The menu does appear on a right click on a ChatNode, but the command does not run. I have actually used almost identical code in other parts of my project so I assume it's correct... but clearly there is an error somewhere.

So where is this command? It is in the view model called 'ChatNodeListViewModel' and I will present it here:

```
void RemoveChatNodeExecute()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Remove chat node");
        return;
    }

    bool CanRemoveChatNode()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public ICommand RemoveChatNodeCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(RemoveChatNodeExecute, CanRemoveChatNode); } }
```

I have also used this in many places throughout my code and it's worked every time but this one.

So, either there's a fault in the code or perhaps a simple mistake. I've checked the name of the command and re-copied it several times. I've checked the other parts of my code where I've used the same code, but I can't see anything wrong. I've cleaned and rebuilt my project just in case.

If anyone can venture a guess, I would be very happy with that.

Comment: How do you apply the ContextMenu and to which element?

Comment: the way i usually solve these issues is by outputting my bindings into labels (or by reading the binding error log). You should try to do the same. usually that way you can detect most issues that involve working with wpf

Comment: If you look at the top piece of posted code (control template), the Border's final attribute is the ContextMenu.

Comment: @Dbl I didn't know you could do that. I wouldn't know how to go about it. Can you provide some more information on how to do that?

Comment: @TheFaithfulLearner Extras/Options/Debugging/OutputWindow/Wpf/Databindings/All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListBox` is not a visual ancestor of a `ContextMenu` but you could set the `Tag` property of the `Border` to the `ListBox` and then bind to the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<Border ... Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ChatNodeMenu}">
```

---

```
<MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.RemoveChatNodeCommand}" />
```

Comment: Blessings to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I have same issue related to conextmenu not able to work on command. could you help me to find solution.
 <GridViewColumn>
                                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>

                                                <Button Content="test2">
                                                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                                                        <ContextMenu>
                                                            <MenuItem Header="rr2" Command="{Binding DataContext.NextCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"  ></MenuItem>
                                                        </ContextMenu>
                                                    </Button.ContextMenu>
                                                </Button>
                                              </DataTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29865330)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).